# How to ensure websocket connection is kept alive in Aleph

Tags: clojure, websocket, aleph

I'm trying to interface with Slack's RTM API with Aleph.

Currently I have this code:

```
(defn connect-socket []
  (let [conn @(http/websocket-client (get-websocket-url))]
    (s/consume #(prn %) conn)
    (send-message conn {:type "ping"}) ;; just to check if send-message works
    (s/on-closed conn (prn "closed"))))
```

It works well for the first few times, and then `conn` stops receiving messages from Slack after some inactivity. Neither does it print "closed", which seems to signify that the stream isn't closed. I'm not quite sure what is happening here.

How can I keep-alive the websocket connection, or auto-reconnect if disconnected? I've seen some code in the wild doing pings, but I don't think I understand the code well enough to adapt it.

Comment: Could you share the links to the `ping` code ?

Comment: https://crossclj.info/ns/unbot-slack/latest/unbot.chat.slack.html#_send-ping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have to send ping messages because :

- websocket deconnections are signaled by a special packet
- there is no way to send this packet in case of ex. a network error
- there is no "auto reconnect" feature, unless you maybe use a library that does it for you (I would personally love [`sente`](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/sente) to support Aleph).

Therefore you have to do some "pings" regularly.
Regarding the code, `on-closed` wants a function as second argument, so :
`(s/on-closed! conn #(prn "closed"))`

Comment: I'm currently pinging it as such:

```
(defn connect-socket []
  (let [conn @(http/websocket-client (get-websocket-url))]
    (s/consume #(prn %) conn)
    (send-message conn {:type "ping"})
    (d/loop []
      (Thread/sleep 5000)
      (send-message conn {:type "ping"})
      (d/recur))
    (s/on-closed conn (prn "closed"))))
```

Comment: I don't see why this would not work for the pings (although I would have used `core.async` myself). I updated my answer to show the "closed" message.

Comment: It works, but now it leaves me wondering how I should manage the websocket connection. Would you store the connection in an agent? I probably need to spawn an async loop checking for pongs, and if so reset the connection somehow.

Comment: You probably meant storing the connections in an atom ? Yes, this is a sensible option. You could have a look at how https://github.com/ptaoussanis/sente does it for instance (they have a SubscriberStore protocol). You could also handle deconnections/reconnections by handling send errors.

Comment: Thanks! I think I need to play around with aleph more. Will mark it as correct because pinging does keep the connection alive for the most part.

Comment: Thanks ! One thing to keep in mind is that the client has to cooperate to make the reconnections.

Comment: what slack does is you send another GET req with a token, and it'll return another WS url for reconnection.

Storing it in an atom works, I can swap! it in a new connection, but I feel like I should just model it as a Component with a lifecycle, perhaps both.

Comment: @jethrokuan even if you model it as a component you will need to have to store them in an atom or something else at some point. I do this with aleph to store SSE connections : a component to hold them, a store backed up by a protocol, and a memory implementation using an atom (this way I should be able to change the storage to something else. At least that's the idea).

Comment: @jethrokuan Also that's interesting about slack, do you have more information about how it works ?

Comment: to get the websocket url in slack you first need to sent an authenticated request to their rtm.start method. https://api.slack.com/methods/rtm.start . It does talk about rate limits, but not about disconnecting due to inactivity.